# How to change data type in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have a SQL Server 2008 database file (`.mdf`) I want to change some data type like from float to int or something like that but I get this error :

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn this option in SQL Server Management Studio off:

> Menu > Tools > Options

[image]

This option is on by default (for safety reasons) and it prevents any changes to table structure that require a complete table rebuild (like changing a datatype of a column)